# How to make copy of email using Action Mailer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, actionmailer

Here is my code:

```
class Mailer < ActionMailer::Base
  def notify(subject:, email_to:, email_from:)
    mail(subject: subject, to: email_to, from: email_from)
  end
end
```

I am calling notify method like below:

```
mail = Mailer.notify(subject: 'This is test email', email_from: ['user1@mail.com'], email_to: ['user2@mail.com'])
mail.deliver
```

Now before calling `mail.deliver`, I want to copy email in another variable(copy_email) with current state and make some changes in copy_email subject and send it to another user.
I am making copy with using.

```
copy_email = mail.clone
    or
copy_email = mail.dup
```

in both cases when I am changing subject of copy_email it's also changing subject of original email.

Anyone have any idea about how to avoid it?

Comment: Why not simply generate another email obj: `mail2 = Mailer.notify(subject: 'another subject', ...)`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, thank you for your suggestion. Changing only subject is not my actual requirement. I mention it as an example. I want to change subject, footer and recipients of the email. I want to avoid creating new object as mail may have attachment, from, subject, html body. Instead I want to use copy of email and make required changes in copy and send it to intended recipients.

Comment: "as mail may have attachment, from, subject, html body" - sooo? I'm not sure I see why that's a problem here.

Comment: In that case I will need to reassign everything(attachment, from, subject, html body) to new mail object. Which I am trying to avoid. making copy will give me all attributes and I only need to change required attributes to send it to different recipients.

Comment: Yes, but why are you trying to avoid it? It's as easy as calling another `Mailer.notify`, just passing your modified input. It's not like you have to write 200 lines of code to do it. Anyway, I don't think copyability was one of design goals here, so you'll likely _have_ to create a brand new object.

Comment: You _could_ try the hard way, `copy_email = Marshal.load(Marshal.dump(mail))`, but use at your own risk. No guarantees that it'll work.

Comment: What version of rails are you using?  I created this repo https://github.com/wmavis/so_rails_mailer with a rake task that clones the mailer object and it seems to work like you want for me.